# Margins displays correctly in Opera, Chrome and IE but not in FF

Tags: css, firefox, margin

I have tried about every option I could think of but I still can't make [this page](http://bellotaestudio.com/test/acabados.php) display correctly in FF.  When you click inside the square, a menu with images appears on the right which is properly aligned in every browser but FF.  I've tweaked the CSS here and there but haven't found a solution.

If I remove the width property from `#acabados_main .image_carousel` on the stylesheet all browsers show the same margins, albeit non-aligned.  But as soon as I give it a width FF is the only one that displays that section differently.

Can someone please take a look and help me see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding float: left; to .general

```
#acabados_main .image_carousel .general {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```